# cycled pictureboxes

Tags: c#, for-loop, picturebox

I need to work with much pictureboxes in one cycle. How can i do this? I tryed this :

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        PictureBox[] pb = new PictureBox[i];
        pb[i].Image = global::Ippodrom.Properties.Resources.horse;
    }
```

But it crashes with:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in Ippodrom.exe

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

What shall I do?

**UPD:** I need to change the picture in created picturebox, not to create a new picturebox.

Comment: How come you start counting from 1 instead of 0?

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop through your existing pictureboxes on your form.

This procedure assumes you have the pictureboxes on the form and not in another container, like a panel.  If so, adjust this code accordingly:

```
foreach (PictureBox pb in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()) {
  pb.Image = global::Ippodrom.Properties.Resources.horse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to create an array of 10 PictureBox and initialize each of them.

What you have done is to create 10 arrays, each of size N, where N is `[1..10]`.

Start by creating an array:

```
PictureBox[] pb = new PictureBox[10];
```

Now you have an array of 10 PixtureBox references. Each of them holds the value 'null'.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // C# arrays are zero-indexed, not one
{
    // Create a new PictureBox and assign it to the array
    pb[i] = new PictureBox();

    // Assign an image to this new PictureBox
    pb[i].Image = global::Ippodrom.Properties.Resources.horse;
}
```

The IndexOutOfRangeException occurs because you used a one-based index instead of zero, but the code was flawed to begin with, so it's not relevant.

Comment: It didn't work, nothing happens. But now no error. I want to change picture in picturebox.

Comment: How are the original `PictureBox`es created?

Comment: In designer. I've found out the solution: PictureBox[] pb = new PictureBox[] { pictureBox1, pictureBox2, pictureBox3, pictureBox4, pictureBox5, pictureBox6, pictureBox7, pictureBox8, pictureBox9, pictureBox10}; foreach (PictureBox i in pb) { i.Image = global::Ippodrom.Properties.Resources.horse; }    But don't think that it is correct enough

Comment: LarsTech has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the Array of PictureBox you don't create any instances. You only declare "space" to hold the References to the Instances.

I guess what you're trying to do is this (but I might be wrong)

```
PictureBox[] pb = new PictureBox[10]; // creates space for 10 elements, first one is 0
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // from 0..9 
    pb[i] = new PictureBox(); // we create the actual thing
    pb[i].Image = global::Ippodrom.Properties.Resources.horse;
}
```

It's probably a lot easier to use a List here

```
IList<PictureBox> pb = new List<PictureBox>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // if you want exactly 10
    var theBox = new PictureBox();
    theBox.Image = global::Ippodrom.Properties.Resources.horse;
    pb.add(theBox);
}
```

if you want to change them

```
IList<PictureBox> pb = new List<PictureBox>() { pictureBox1 /* etc */ };
foreach(PictureBox p in pb) {
    p.Image = global::Ippodrom.Properties.Resources.horse;
}
```

If you want every Picturebox in the Control go with the by LarsTech :)

Comment: I need to change image in created pictureboxes

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to do here ;) the above code should work for every iterable collection including arrays.

Comment: I've got 10 PIctureBoxes created via designer. Now i need to change image in each of them.